SassC syntax error when updating Rails 5.1 to 7.1
My app is updated from 5.1, and basic functions are running normally on local server.
I'm trying to run the old system tests to see if paperclip is going to fail (am going active storage regardless), and I guess there's an email sent during factory_bot_rails user initialization which possibly results in this error that appears briefly in browser if run headless=false that is beyond my capacity:
SassC::SyntaxError in Pages#home
Showing /home/dave/bananashack/app/views/user_mailer/welcome_email.html.erb where line # raised:

Error: "calc(100vh - 110px)" is not a number for `min'
        on line 1:33074 of stdin, in function `min`
        from line 1:33074 of stdin
>> x;flex:1;flex-direction:column;max-height:min(650px,calc(100vh - 110px));ove
   ------------------------------------------^
Extracted source (around line #50):
48    line = Native.context_get_error_line(context)
49
50    raise SyntaxError.new(message, filename: filename, line: line)
51  end
52
53  css = Native.context_get_output_string(context)
              
Tip: You may want to add gem 'error_highlight', '>= 0.4.0' into your Gemfile, which will display the fine-grained error location.

Rails.root: /home/dave/bananashack

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
sassc (2.4.0) lib/sassc/engine.rb:50:in `render'
sassc-rails (2.1.2) lib/sassc/rails/compressor.rb:29:in `call'
sprockets (4.2.1) lib/sprockets/sass_compressor.rb:30:in `call'
sprockets (4.2.1) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:84:in `call_processor'
sprockets (4.2.1) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:66:in `block in call_processors'
sprockets (4.2.1) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:65:in `reverse_each'
sprockets (4.2.1) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:65:in `call_processors'
sprockets (4.2.1) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:184:in `load_from_unloaded'
sprockets (4.2.1) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:59:in `block in load'
sprockets (4.2.1) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:339:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
sprockets (4.2.1) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:43:in `load'
sprockets (4.2.1) lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:44:in `block in load'
concurrent-ruby (1.3.3) lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/map.rb:207:in `block in fetch_or_store'
concurrent-ruby (1.3.3) lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/map.rb:187:in `fetch'
concurrent-ruby (1.3.3) lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/map.rb:206:in `fetch_or_store'
sprockets (4.2.1) lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:44:in `load'
sprockets (4.2.1) lib/sprockets/bundle.rb:32:in `block in call'
/home/dave/.rbenv/versions/3.1.4/lib/ruby/3.1.0/set.rb:511:in `each_key'
/home/dave/.rbenv/versions/3.1.4/lib/ruby/3.1.0/set.rb:511:in `each'
sprockets (4.2.1) lib/sprockets/bundle.rb:31:in `call'
sprockets (4.2.1) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:84:in `call_processor'
sprockets (4.2.1) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:66:in `block in call_processors'
sprockets (4.2.1) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:65:in `reverse_each'
sprockets (4.2.1) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:65:in `call_processors'
sprockets (4.2.1) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:184:in `load_from_unloaded'
sprockets (4.2.1) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:59:in `block in load'
sprockets (4.2.1) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:339:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
sprockets (4.2.1) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:43:in `load'
sprockets (4.2.1) lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:44:in `block in load'
concurrent-ruby (1.3.3) lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/map.rb:207:in `block in fetch_or_store'
concurrent-ruby (1.3.3) lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/map.rb:187:in `fetch'
concurrent-ruby (1.3.3) lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/map.rb:206:in `fetch_or_store'
sprockets (4.2.1) lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:44:in `load'
sprockets (4.2.1) lib/sprockets/base.rb:81:in `find_asset'
sprockets (4.2.1) lib/sprockets/base.rb:88:in `find_all_linked_assets'
sprockets (4.2.1) lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:125:in `each'
sprockets (4.2.1) lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:125:in `to_a'
sprockets (4.2.1) lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:125:in `block (2 levels) in find'
concurrent-ruby (1.3.3) lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/safe_task_executor.rb:24:in `block in execute'
concurrent-ruby (1.3.3) lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/synchronization/mutex_lockable_object.rb:48:in `block in synchronize'
concurrent-ruby (1.3.3) lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/synchronization/mutex_lockable_object.rb:48:in `synchronize'
concurrent-ruby (1.3.3) lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/synchronization/mutex_lockable_object.rb:48:in `synchronize'
concurrent-ruby (1.3.3) lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/safe_task_executor.rb:22:in `execute'
concurrent-ruby (1.3.3) lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/promise.rb:564:in `block in realize'
concurrent-ruby (1.3.3) lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:359:in `run_task'
concurrent-ruby (1.3.3) lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:350:in `block (3 levels) in create_worker'
concurrent-ruby (1.3.3) lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:341:in `loop'
concurrent-ruby (1.3.3) lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:341:in `block (2 levels) in create_worker'
concurrent-ruby (1.3.3) lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:340:in `catch'
concurrent-ruby (1.3.3) lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:340:in `block in create_worker'


Looks like it's SassC syntax error not Rspec and sassc isn't supported anymore.  It might be worth changing over to dartsass or even use esbuild and the sass javascript package.  Try installing a new rails app with rails new new_app --css=sass or rails new new_app1 --css=bootstrap to see how scss is setup in a new rails app.

Thank you. --css=sass failed to build gem native extension on sass-embedded 1.77.5 due to undefined method `parse' for #<Psych::Parser: etc , and   --css=bootstrap resulted with The template [/home/dave/.rbenv/versions/3.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/cssbundling-rails-1.4.0/lib/install/bootstrap/install.rb] could not be loaded. Error: No such file or directory - npx.   ....... no error in development performing the same action

OK, the second one requires node, install node.js before you do that one.  I'm not sure about the first one. Try gem install sass-embedded and see if that gives you a better error message.

Try updating rubygems with gem update --system.  That should help with installing sass-embedded.

I appreciate that, thank you - will return to this in a bit
